# How can I add Formula in Guided Decision table in Drools Kie Workbench?

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm, kie

I try to add a formula for calculation salary according to salary?

```
if(age>25)

Salary = Salary + cofactor *Salary
```

My RULE :

[image]

Source : The Kie Workbench created below code ;

```
package com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2;

//from row number: 1
rule "Row 1 GDT1" extends "GR1"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        f1 : Employee( age >= 25 )
    then
        modify( f1 ) {
                setSalary( 0.0 )
        }
end
```

But I can not set salary by using :
Salary = Salary + cofactor *Salary

My Desired rule must be below by using guided rule table:

```
package com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2;

//from row number: 1
rule "Row 1 GDT1" extends "GR1"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        f1 : Employee( age >= 25 )
    then
        modify( f1 ) {
                setSalary( f1.Salary + f1.cofactor *f1.Salary )
        }
end
```

How can I add Formula of (setSalary( f1.Salary + f1.cofactor *f1.Salary )) in Guided Decision table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced such a case and did the following:
Bind a condition column and add action brl fragment column - modify value of filed - field value formula and add my formula.

And the end I have this source of gui table

```
package com.myspace.project;
//from row number: 1

    rule "Row 1 gui"
        dialect "mvel"
        when
            $c : Customer( $b : balance, $d : discount)
        then
            modify( $c ) {
                    setIncome( $b*$d*10 )
            }
    end
```